# С помощью MAP найти максимальный номер строки, в которой встречается значение

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Найти максимальный номер строки с помощью формулы просто - =ArrayFormula(НАИБОЛЬШИЙ(СТРОКА($A$3:$A$21)*($A$3:$A$21=A3);1))

Когда таких формул больше тысячи, это ощутимо подвешивает файл, после каждого изменения 5-7 секунд идёт пересчёт - достало :)

Использовал МАР - получается просто нумерация строк.
=map(A3:A21;LAMBDA(qwer;ArrayFormula(НАИБОЛЬШИЙ(СТРОКА(qwer)*($A$3:qwer=A3);1))))

Пожалуйста, подскажите, что нужно изменить, чтобы МАР возвращала наибольший номер строки, в которой встречается значение?

[Пример тут](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lJ6ED1GGd8Kqk28Z8hAqER9YSGzvVS5bFdXt5Vz_fJY/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы неправильно учли диапазоны, в остальном ваша формула верна

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(LET(
  _range;A3:A21;
  MAP(_range;LAMBDA(_row;LARGE(ROW(_range)*(_range=_row);1)))
))
```

[Таблица](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IHDKe-5Tzvq8et8l85qo3ZKaL38HR2WUFpXFiV2S4iI/edit#gid=401575838&range=E3) с решением

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарю! Препкрасное решение!